Laymen trying to understand the uncertainty principle
I'm confused, please help.
In the double slit experiment, when we don't observe which hole the particle was in (leaving the position uncertain), the particle behaves like a wave. When we do observe which hole the particle was in (gain knowledge of position), it behaves more like a particle and follows the classical trajectory of a particle. But shouldn't knowing which hole the particle was in, corresponding to greater certainty of position, had caused the loss of the knowledge of the momentum, deviating the particle from its classical trajectory?
In the single slit version, if slit size is very small, momentum becomes very indefinite and we lose the classical path of the particle in proportion to how small the slit size becomes. This being the case, how is it that in the double slit version of the experiment, the classical path is retained when position knowledge increases?
What am I missing here?

It might be as follows: if a system is constrained very symmetrically, it tends to be underdetermined... But once a little a-symmetry is introduced, e.g. by giving photons that pass through the left (but not right) slit a little nudge, then this originally underdetermined system can easily become upgraded to a fully determined one. By this definition, anything that introduces asymmetry to the originally underdetermined system have a good chance of collapsing the solution of the system (personified by $\Psi$) into a whole other outcome scenario.

This might help - The more general uncertainty principle, regarding Fourier transforms

photon is not really a particle ... the photon always has its wave properties ...diffraction is due to the EM field interactions of the slit material with the photon. The smaller the slit the more interaction/diffraction.

I think you misunderstood...
In the observed double slit experiment, the particle does not follow a precise classical path. High position certainty increases momentum uncertainty, causing broad diffraction patterns, not precise classical trajectories, and eliminating interference fringes.
When observing which slit a particle goes through in the double slit experiment, high momentum uncertainty causes diffraction. We see two overlapping single-slit diffraction patterns without interference fringes, as the wave function collapses, eliminating the interference seen when both slits are unobserved.

Correct me if I am wrong!
